# How to avoid overlapping text using CSS?

Tags: string, html, css, browser

For example StackOverflow, if I use `Firebug` and change my name to a long name, or I change the number of badges to a long integer, how do I manage this with `CSS` to avoid one to enter in the other?

Comment: `white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `overflow: hidden`, `overflow: scroll` or a similar value of the css `overflow` property.

Comment: ah, because i use a variable so it's only now that i've tested and found that a user can put a long variable value and make everything go out :'(
thank you :)